# Remove parts of line that are not contained within multiline

Tags: postgis, postgresql, differences

PostgreSQL 14.6, Postgis 3.2

I have two tables, `new_geom` and `original_geom`

`new_geom` is a derivation of `original_geom` that merged some lines that touched and had the same properties. It worked fairly well, but created some errant line segments. I am now trying to remove those segments.

Below I am getting the difference between the new geom and the old geom:

```
WITH original_geom AS (
    SELECT (st_collect(geom)) AS geom FROM original_geom_backup
)
SELECT ogc_fid, ST_Difference(c.geom, og.geom) AS geom
FROM new_geom c JOIN original_geom og ON NOT st_within(c.geom, og.geom)
ORDER BY ogc_fid
```

Next I want to use that result to remove those "difference segments" from the new lines:

```
WITH original_geom AS (
    SELECT (st_collect(geom)) AS geom FROM original_geom_backup
)
, difference AS (
    SELECT ogc_fid, ST_Difference(ng.geom, og.geom) AS geom
    FROM new_geom ng JOIN original_geom og ON NOT st_within(ng.geom, og.geom)
    ORDER BY ogc_fid
)
SELECT ng.ogc_fid, ST_Difference(ng.geom, d.geom) FROM new_geom ng join difference d on ng.ogc_fid = d.ogc_fid
```

However, this returns the `new_geom` geoms completely unmodified. How can I rewrite this query to actually remove those differences?

EDIT:

The original lines are in black, the new in red. The red line was transformed into a line comprising:

- the correct line, running along high street (within the black line)
- the errant line, not contained by the black line
  [image: example lines]

Comment: @BERA added a screenshot

Comment: create a small buffer around your original lines and delete each red lines that are not fully contains by those buffers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to also remove the geometries that aren't contained in any of the lines you could try this:

```
with d as (
    select st_difference((select st_collect(geom) from new_geom), (select st_collect(geom) from original_geom_backup)) geom
)
select n.ogc_fid, ST_Difference(n.geom, d.geom) geom FROM new_geom n, d;
```

or this, which is a bit more efficient:

```
with d as (
    select ogc_fid, st_difference(geom, (select st_collect(geom) from original_geom_backup)) geom
    from new_geom
)
select n.ogc_fid, ST_Difference(n.geom, d.geom) geom FROM new_geom n join d on n.ogc_fid = d.ogc_fid;
```

Comment: Hey @jbalk, my apologies, when I said "How can I rewrite this query to actually remove those differences?", I was being imprecise. I understand how to actually store them in pg, it's just that the query was not removing differences from them. I looked a bit further into the data, and 3 of the "differences" are not actually contained within the new geom, so they don't get removed by st_difference. The other ones work.

Comment: You need to remove that st_within filter to catch those lines that are completely outside the old lines